# How to style items in a DataTemplate that are selected using a DataTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, stylesheet, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I have created a Listview that uses two different data templates to display different items in the list one is a label and a button and the other is just a label. The template is selected using the DataTemplateSelector. My question is how do you apply styling to both data templates such as highlighting on hovering over without repeating the xaml?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443600/is-there-a-way-to-use-data-template-inheritance-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Might help having a look at this sample:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Ref to sample code (also at the bottom in the above article):

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7791