# Inheriting / BasedOn datatemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, basedon

I have a `DataTemplate` that I am using within my WPF application -

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="mattersTemplate">
    <Border Name="border" BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5" Margin="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="FileRef:"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=FileRef}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Description:"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Priority:"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I then (in a `DocumentSetTemplateSelector` class) define which template to use;

What I would like to do / know is; 
Create 4 other templates that would inherit this above template AND then allow certain attributes to be over-written;

An example (this template inherits from the above class) - so they look the same;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="documentSet_Accounting">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding mattersTemplate}" 
         ContentTemplate="{StaticResource mattersTemplate}">
    </ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>
```

I would like for there to be a style attached to this (if possible) so to get this effect;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="documentSet_Accounting">
    <ContentPresenter fontsize="20" Content="{Binding mattersTemplate}" 
         ContentTemplate="{StaticResource mattersTemplate}">
    </ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>
```

or

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="documentSet_Accounting">
    <ContentPresenter Style="AccountingStyle" Content="{Binding mattersTemplate}" 
         ContentTemplate="{StaticResource mattersTemplate}">
    </ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use data-template inheritance in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443600/is-there-a-way-to-use-data-template-inheritance-in-wpf)

Comment: The problem is that i am unsure as to how to add a "style" to the documentSet_Accounting template (so that the fontsize for instance, within that template) would be different... (appoligies if i didnt ask clearly enough.

Comment: Hi ArsenMkrt
I had seen that post and that is all about how to link a Datatemplate with another, there is nothing as how to add a style to the inheriting template(s).

Comment: There is no inheritance. Only composition as the link explains..

Comment: Basically, i would like to add a style to my documentSet_Accounting template that would effect the look of the ContentTemplate="{StaticResource mattersTemplate} (i.e. so that way i can use this ContentTemplate="{StaticResource mattersTemplate} on all my datatemplates and then adjust the (eg) Fontsize individually, if needed)

Comment: If you want to modify a template you can place a new ContentControl in it and provide the Template for that via the View model. Or you can use Attached properties to modify properties inside a template. You can also make the attached properties inherited which means you can set the property higher up in the tree so it will get used somewhere inside the template.

Answer (score 1):

How about using style inheritance within the templates rather than template inheritance?

```
<Style x:Key="mattersTemplateStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="documentSet_AccountingStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource mattersTemplateStyle}">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="20"/>            
</Style>
<DataTemplate x:Key="mattersTemplate">
    <Border Name="border" BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5" Margin="5">
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource mattersTemplateStyle}">
            [...]
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="documentSet_Accounting">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource documentSet_AccountingStyle}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding mattersTemplate}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource mattersTemplate}"></ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi Stephen,
That seems to be on the right path - thank you.
What i am looking for is the same thing but i would like to change a single attribute within the grid, not set the style for the entire grid.
i.e. 
This grid currently loads 5 entries (from a static class) and one of the textbox's contain the field called DocumentSet, i am trying to make it so that all the values conform to the same grid look but depending on the DocumentSet value (i.e. "Accounting") change the the font colour only.

Comment: Hi @Hexie sorry it's been a while, are you still looking at this problem? I'm not sure what the difference is between setting a style on the Grid inside the documentSet_Accounting template versus just setting the font size directly on the content presenter. I'd have thought both those operations would do the same thing? In my above example, *all* your documentSet displays have a green foreground colour (that is part of the "base" style), whereas only the documentSet with value "Accounting" would have the font size of 20 as that is in the "derived" style.