# How to add same object to resource dictionary with different keys in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I want to have the same data template specified for different subclasses of generic class in recource dictionary. What is the simple way to achieve this?

```
class Base<T> {}

class DerivedInt : Base<int> {}

class DerivedDouble : Base<double> {}

<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DerivedInt}">
        <!--content goes here-->
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DerivedDouble}">
        <!--same content as above goes here-->
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So I actually want to specify the same content of data templates without type it again

Comment: do you want these datatemplates to be automatically assigned.. coz you are using x:key so you will be using this key and if the content of the templates are exactly same then why do you want two different Templates? you can define one and access it with same key at multiple places

Comment: Well, we can throw these keys away, I need only DataType. I removed them from sample in question

Comment: Here's [a post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4443726/1378699) about DataTemplate inheritance that should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same template for all types I suppose you are going to use the property values converted to common types as string or object in the template.

Create a wrapper class for those derived objects with the properties you want to bind to the template. These wrapper class needs one data template

```
public class DerivedWrapper
{
   //Properties you want to bind

   public DerivedWrapper(DerivedInt dInt)
   {
      //Set the properties 
   }

   public DerivedWrapper(DerivedDouble dDouble)
   {
      //Set the properties
   }
}
```

And then

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DerivedWrapper}">
        <!--content goes here-->
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be overcomplicated comparing to answer in the comment from Raúl Nuño to question