# How to make a base data template implemented by data templates using child class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

If I want to create a common display for a parent property, how can I make it show up in data templates using that use derrived types?

Let's say I have this model.

```
class Animal
{
    public string Name;
}

class Dog:Animal
{
    public string Breed;
}

class Bird:Animal
{
    public bool CanFly;
}
```

I want to display a textblock for the Animal name across all dog and bird data templates. My first instinct was to just dive right in with the data templates. You can imagine this didn't lead anywhere.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Animal}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Dog}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Breed}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Bird}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CanFly}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

My actual project of course has an MVVM set up, but I figure this would be enough to go on for the question.

So again, how can I create a common data template to be used across data templates that use a child type? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use data-template inheritance in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443600/is-there-a-way-to-use-data-template-inheritance-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for a layout to "inherit" another layout. However, you can make each child layout display the inherited subset of properties, while avoiding code duplication:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Animal}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Dog}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ContentPresenter
                 ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type local:Animal}}"
                 Content="{Binding}"
            />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Breed}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Bird}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ContentPresenter
                 ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type local:Animal}}"
                 Content="{Binding}" 
            />

            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CanFly}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @MattThomas You're welcome. Problem is, I've just tried writing this. It looks fine in the editor window, but then I get a strange StackOverflowException when running it. I'd be interested to know if it works for you.

Comment: I don't think you need both the Content and the ContentTemplate. If you're doing a `Content="{Binding"}` then the fact that you've already declared a DataTemplate for the type that it's bound to should be enough.